# Chicago United Center to Midway Airport

Tags: taxis, event-based-effects, chicago, mdw

I am attending my first Blackhawks game on Sunday afternoon and have to catch a flight out of Midway right after the game. What's the quickest way to get to Midway from the United Center if I don't want to use public transit? Where is the best place to catch a taxi?

Various websites are worrying me as they say getting a cab is a nightmare. Any thoughts on arranging an Uber ride?

Comment: If you change your mind about public transportation, see *[Taking the CTA to United Center, Chicago](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44080)*

Comment: And have you considered what you'll do if the game goes into overtime?

Comment: yes I have and might have to change flites or stay another nite.

Answer (score 5):

Getting a taxi when 1,000 other people are trying to do the same thing at the same location is practically impossible. I doubt you could get an Uber either, at least not without paying an insane surge price.

Barring having a really good friend to pick you up and drive you, your best bet here really is public transit.

The 19 and 20 buses will stop on Madison in front of the United Center after the game, but these also will be crowded and you may still have to wait a while.

To really beat the crowds here, I would walk a few blocks to the nearest L station (~ 10 mins). Go east toward the lake down Madison to Ashland, turn left, and pick up the [green](http://www.transitchicago.com/assets/1/greenline_schedules/Ashland.pdf) or [pink](http://www.transitchicago.com/assets/1/pinkline_schedules/ashland.pdf) line from Ashland station to the loop (~ 5 mins). Transfer at Clark/Lake or Adams/Wabash to the [orange](http://www.transitchicago.com/assets/1/orangeline_schedules/Clark.pdf) line all the way to Midway (~ 27 mins). At the time you should be getting out of the game (it starts at 2pm so I figure you should be leaving around 5pm), trains are still running every 10-12 minutes, so you should have little difficulty getting to Midway by 6pm.

---

Another option is the [airport shuttle](http://www.airportexpress.com/). You can book this in advance and ask them to pick you up somewhere nearby. But with the expected traffic congestion, this may not save you any time, or it might even cost you time.

Comment: Another option would be to take the #9 or #50 south on Ashland or Damen (respectively) until they intersect with the Orange Line and transfer over there.  The Google Maps trip planner pegs these options as marginally quicker, at ~40–50 minutes instead of ~50–60.  (That said, it's been a while since I've taken the CTA and I have no idea how reliable the online schedules are these days.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert That could work too, but I would avoid the bus in this particular scenario, because the timing is a lot less predictable.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I think the route you mentioned in the 4th paragraph I am calling "the L route" is what i'm seeing on google maps here https://goo.gl/maps/cWPibmUdSqt.  I liked the taking the Ls instead of taking taxis nice suggestion.

Comment: thanks everyone for your suggestions. will see how it goes.

Comment: @DanielMiladinovich Yes, Google seems to have reproduced my route precisely. :)